# Why does my Python code inserts a Subelement Twice to an XML file?

Tags: python, xml

I wrote a python code that inserts subelements that contain content into another bigger subelement. It does work but the problem is that every subelement is inserted twice for some reason. I checked out the code and I am not sure why it happens, can anyone point me the problem in my code? I know it is not the most efficent way,but I'll try to improve it soon.
Code:

```
import random
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
map_file = "D:\\Users\\micha\\Desktop\\ram-and-michael\\binaries\\data\\mods\\public\\maps\\scenarios\\TestML.xml"
units_file = os.listdir("D:\\Users\\micha\\Desktop\\ram-and-michael\\binaries\\data\\mods\\public\\simulation\\templates\\units") # all the units in the file. 
armies_types = ("athen", "brit", "cart", "gaul", "iber", "kush", "mace", "maur", "pers", "ptol", "rome", "sele", "spart")
map_tree = ET.parse(map_file)
army_list = [] # units that can spawn in a game
    army1 = generate_units() # returns a list of strings
    army2 = generate_units()
    flag = 10 # id 

    map_root = map_tree.getroot()
    Entites = map_tree.find("Entities")
    Entites = delete_Entitites(Entites)


    for unit in army1:
        Entity = ET.SubElement(Entites,"Entity", uid= str(flag))
        Template = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Template").text = "units/" + unit
        Player = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Player").text = "1" 
        Position = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Position",x="326.66935" ,z="321.1384")
        Orientation = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Orientation",y="2.35621")
        flag += 1
        Entites.append(Entity)
        print(flag)
    for unit in army2:

        Entity = ET.SubElement(Entites,"Entity", uid= str(flag))
        Template = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Template").text = "units/" + unit
        Player = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Player").text = "2"
        Position = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Position",x="326.66935" ,z="321.1384")
        Orientation = ET.SubElement(Entity,"Orientation",y="2.35621")
        flag += 1 
        Entites.append(Entity)
        print(flag)
    indent(map_root)

    map_tree.write(map_file,encoding = "utf-8",xml_declaration = True)
```

Output:

```
<Entities>
        <Entity uid="10">
          <Template>units/gaul_hero_vercingetorix_infantry</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="10">
          <Template>units/gaul_hero_vercingetorix_infantry</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="11">
          <Template>units/gaul_catafalque</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="11">
          <Template>units/gaul_catafalque</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="12">
          <Template>units/gaul_infantry_javelinist_e</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="12">
          <Template>units/gaul_infantry_javelinist_e</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="13">
          <Template>units/gaul_hero_vercingetorix</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="13">
          <Template>units/gaul_hero_vercingetorix</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="14">
          <Template>units/gaul_cavalry_swordsman_a</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="14">
          <Template>units/gaul_cavalry_swordsman_a</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="15">
          <Template>units/gaul_hero_vercingetorix_infantry</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="15">
          <Template>units/gaul_hero_vercingetorix_infantry</Template>
          <Player>1</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="16">
          <Template>units/rome_infantry_swordsman_a</Template>
          <Player>2</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="16">
          <Template>units/rome_infantry_swordsman_a</Template>
          <Player>2</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="17">
          <Template>units/rome_catafalque</Template>
          <Player>2</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="17">
          <Template>units/rome_catafalque</Template>
          <Player>2</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity uid="18">
          <Template>units/rome_champion_infantry_barracks</Template>
          <Player>2</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
      <Entity uid="18">
          <Template>units/rome_champion_infantry_barracks</Template>
          <Player>2</Player>
          <Position x="326.66935" z="321.1384" />
          <Orientation y="2.35621" />
        </Entity>
      </Entities>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a SubElement you specify the parent, so it is already added to the parent element.

After creating your SubElement you are appending it to the parent again at line:

```py
Entites.append(Entity)
```

So your SubElement will repeat.